# Plotly and Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, google-colaboratory, plotly-python

I am very knew to Google Colab, given that I couldn't get interactive plots using matplotlib I am using the Plotly express library for colab.

I have a dataframe (Pandas) called pdd of dimensions [15678, 120]

I am trying to plot all the columns in the same graph.

In the code below, I am first trying to plot Column 2 and 3 but it is creating the vector [2,3] instead of indexing those columns.

Does anyone know how to index columns using plotly express? or is it just possible to plot one variable at the time?

```
import plotly.express as px
from IPython.display import HTML

time =np.arange(len(pdd))

fig = px.scatter(data_frame=pdd, x=time, y=[2,3])
fig.show()
HTML(fig.to_html())
```

Comment: Try replacing your `fig` code with `px.scatter(data_frame=pdd, x=time, y=[pdd.iloc[:,2], pdd.iloc[:,3]])`. The `.iloc` function grabs the data in the dataframe at the indices `[rows, cols]`. The `:` as the first parameter means all rows, and then the 2 and 3 are columns 2 and 3 (0-based).

Comment: You can also replace the `y` variable in the `px.scatter()` function with `y=[pdd['Col2'], pdd['Col3']]` where `Col2` and `Col3` are the names of your second and third columns